# C notation: pointer to array of chars (string)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Why are pointers to arrays of `char`s (ie. `string`s) written as below:

```
char *path
```

Instead of:

```
char *path[]
```

or something like that?

How could I create a pointer to a `char` and not a `string`?

Comment: Which book are you learning C from?

Comment: char *path[] is a pointer to a pointer to char. That's the same as char **path. char path[] or char *path are both pointers to char.

Comment: @puller The only context where `char *path[]` is the same as `char **path` is in a function parameter list.

Comment: @puller: `char *path[]` is an array of pointers.  In many contexts `path` will evaluate to a `char**`, but it is still in fact an array, not a pointer.  For example, you couldn't say `path = &some_char_pointer;` like you could if `path` were declared as a `char**`.

Comment: A pointer to array of chars would be a `char (*ptr)[length];`. Hardly any use for that, since array addresses aren't mutable.

Answer (score 8):

`char *path` is not a pointer to a string, it is a pointer to a `char`.

It may be the case that `char *path` semantically points to a "string", but that is just in the interpretation of the data.

In c, strings often use `char *`, but only under the assumption that the pointer is to the first character of the string, and the other characters are subsequent in memory until you reach a null terminator. That does not change the fact that it is just a pointer to a character.

Answer (score 4):

`char *path` is a pointer to char. It can be used to point at a single char as well as to point at a char in a zero-terminated array (a string)

`char *path[]` is an array of pointers to char.

A pointer to an array of char would be `char (*path)[N]` where N (the size of the array) is part of the pointer's type. Such pointers are not widely used because the size of the array would have to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

`char *path[]` is an array of pointers. `char *path` is a single pointer.

> How could I create a pointer to a char and not a string?

A 'string' in C is simply a pointer to a `char` that has the convention of being the start of a sequence of characters that ends in '\0'.  You can declare a pointer to a single `char` the same way, you just have to take care to use it according to the data it's actually pointing to.

This is similar to the concept that a `char` in C is just an integer with a rather limited range.  You can use that data type as a number, as a true/false value, or as a character that should be displayed as a glyph at some point.  The interpretation of what's in the `char` variable is up to the programmer.

Not having a first class, full-fledged 'string' data type is something that distinguishes C from most other high level languages. I'll let you decide for yourself whether it distinguishes C in a good or a bad way.

Comment: Speaking on the question title, *is* there a use for `char (*ptr)[]`? I can't seem to think of a situation where it'd be useful, especially compared to a `char *ptr[]`